# prevent enter key from closing alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want to make sure that a user has to manually close a javascript alert, and that the user can't simply quit out of the alert by pressing enter.

(This sounds malicious, but in the application you press enter a lot and I need to make sure they don't miss the important information the alert gives them).

I have tried setting the document.onkeydown to no avail:

```
document.onkeydown = disabled;
```

and then in the disabled function

```
function disabled(event) {
    if (event.keyCode==13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

is there a way to accomplish this without having to switch over to using modals?

Comment: Change the call to `alert()` to some custom modal window implementation.

Comment: Slight nitpick... Pressing enter *is* a manual action, the user *is* "manually closing the alert".

Comment: @Halcyon: The end of the question: *"is there a way to accomplish this **without having to switch over to using modals**?"* (my emphasis)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not sure why you made that comment. `window.alert()` is a modal. I guess the emphasis is on _custom_. If you're unsure of the term, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Comment: @Halcyon: To me it's clear that the OP's talking about a custom modal window implementation there. But it's not a big deal. Re your edit: Of course I'm sure of the term. I also have a decent grasp of web programming vernacular. Guess what "modal" means there, 99 out of 100 times.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is there a way to accomplish this without having to switch over to using modals?

No. The `alert` is outside the document and you can't add any event handling to it. The path you've already identified (switching to a "modal" element) is the way you'll have to go. It also has the advantage you can improve styling, prevent the browser from suppressing the alerts, etc. There's some refactoring required to handle the async completion, of course.

Answer (score 0):

A kludgy solution would be for the alert to always be in the foreground so they will see it, but to grey out the alert by having windows focus on some other object, so that the user's 'enter' will go to that instead.